# Check Image Scanning Class or Application

Tags: c#, image-processing, banking

We are looking for a way to scan a check in, like the banks do, and be able to read the check information to send to the bank. We'd like to integrate this into our software so it's seamless.

I am not sure what I'd be looking for at this point. I know I don't have the knowledge to write anything like that but I'm sure there are companies who do this. If you know of a class or api, open source or paid, can you please give me some direction as to where I should be looking?

Thanks!

Comment: Obviously you'll need to go shopping for a scanner.  There's a great range of types and capabilities, the specific model will determine what kind of code you need to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for either a scanning library, and a OCR library, or a MICR library. MICR is (was?) the standard for reading checks (and there are many specific MICR scanners, with check standards like VersaScan, etc.)... much better than standard OCR.

I have never done anything like that in C# so I can't provide any concrete proven SDK, but most check scanners (MICR ones) should have available SDK's on their manufacturer's websites, so that's a place to start.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions on a scanner that has an SDK with it?

Comment: [This](http://www.inliteresearch.com/products/index.php) (look at the bottom) will supposedly read the MICR lines in a check from any image (you can use TWAIN or WIA to aquire from any source).

Comment: [Here's another SDK](http://www.allmypapers.com/micr-ocr.html)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a scanner with built-in MICR support, but these tend to be expensive and I'm not sure if there are any common libraries for programming with them.

Another option is to use any low-cost quality scanner and recognize the text from the scanned pages using software. There are some free scanning and OCR libraries but they tend to be hard to use and usually give low recognition rates. There's an SDK that I used before for scanning and OCR of regular documents (not bank check) and they had a special module for MICR.

I haven't tried the MICR module but there's a [demo project for it on this forum](http://support.leadtools.com/SupportPortal/cs/forums/40882/ShowPost.aspx).